# Hiding MudText dynamically in blazor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, mudblazor

I am using Mudtext binded to a property:

```
<MudTextField Value="@MyClass.Age" Label="Age"  />
```

I can't find way to hide this textbox dynamically based on some property.

Comment: Can't you just not render it based on some variable? That's how things are done when using most Blazor components libraries.

Comment: @maciek can you share example on what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you don't want to display something based on a value of a variable you use in your Razor page:

```
@if(shown)
{
    <MudTextField Value="@MyClass.Age" Label="Age"  />
}

@code
{
   bool shown = true;
   private void SomeFunction()
   {
       shown = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok this works. Strange that blazor component dont have visible property on textbox

Comment: I think it's up to a designer of the component library.